# Optimize a case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, subquery

I have a long list of:

```
update wi
   SET class
   case
        WHEN wi.column = 'a' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl1  where code = 1)
        WHEN wi.column = 'b' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl1  where code = 2)
        WHEN wi.column = 'c' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl1  where code = 3)
        WHEN wi.column = 'd' THEN (select top 1 from lookup_tbl1  where code = 80)

   end
   SET name
   case
        WHEN wi.column2 = 'Chris' THEN (select top 1 from table1  where code = 1)
        WHEN wi.column2 = 'david' THEN (select top 1 from table1  where code = 2)
        WHEN wi.column2 = 'tan' THEN (select top 1 from table1  where code = 3)
        WHEN wi.column2 = 'drake' THEN (select top 1 from table1  where code = 80)
        WHEN wi.column2 = 'x' THEN ..........

   end
   SET department
   case
        WHEN wi.column3 like 'd.d%' then 'Director D'
        WHEN wi.column3 like '%AC'  then  'Accounting'

   end

FROM transform_tbl wi WHERE flag is null
```

I'm cleaning up the transform_tbl table. I need to replace abbreviations with actual names and fix the data in that table.
is there another way or a better way to do this?

Comment: Its actually called a case expression - precisely because its not a statement.

Comment: You need to include some of the outer statement so we can see where column comes from and what other tables are involved.

Comment: pls show full query and data structure

Comment: Your query is syntactically incorrect because the subqueries need to select something.  It would also help to see the rest of the query.  And to understand why you are using `top` without `order by`.

Comment: I added more details to the question. @DaleK

Comment: "Is there another way to do this?"  Yes.  Don't.  Simply `join` in the reference tables when you query the table.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the `case` to the subquery, like so:

```
(
    select top (1) col
    from table1
    where code = case column
        when 'a' then 1
        when 'b' then 2
        when 'c' then 3
        when 'd' then 80
    end
)
```

Notes:

- your subqueries where missing an actual column in the `select` clause; I assumed `col`
- further optimizations are likely possible, but you would need to show us your entire query, and explain its intent - you might want to ask a new question for this

Comment: @user7331796 in fact this answer shows you how to do it, just replace each column update with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on `table1(code)`, you method is probably fine.  Well, that is other than the fact that it is syntactically incorrect.  The subqueries need to select something.

That said, I would restructure the code so there is not some magic correspondence between the `code` and `column`.  For instance, `table1` should perhaps have the letters identifying the rows.  That would greatly simplify the query:

```
(select top (1) ? from table1 t1 where t1.letter = ?.column)
```

No `case` expression would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Best option is a separate table for this, that can map `column` values to `code` values, perhaps with an index. Then you could join to it rather than needing a complicated `case` expression.

But failing that, you can create the mapping with a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```sql
INNER JOIN (VALUES 
    ('a', 1), 
    ('b', 2), 
    ('c', 3),
    ('d', 80),
    ('x', ... )   
) AS map(col, code) ON map.col = [column]
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.code = map.code
```

Alternatively, given the `top 1`, you may need an `apply`:

```sql
INNER JOIN (VALUES 
    ('a', 1), 
    ('b', 2), 
    ('c', 3),
    ('d', 80),
    ('x', ... )   
) AS map(col, code) ON map.col = column
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ? FROM table1 WHERE table1.code = map.code) t1
```

But as was said in other answers, we need to know what columns you're looking for.

Finally, since we don't have the full original query, I can't tell you exactly how to integrate this with the rest of the code, or even whether you want `INNER` or `LEFT` join.